# How to serialize the object containing List of objects?

Tags: java, serialization

I have a class with the following fields and i want to persist it to a file.But it is throwing the following exception...
java.io.NotSerializableException: ****.VehicleDetailsCollection .

```
public class VehicleDetailsCollectionWrapper implements java.io.Serializable{

private String updatedTime;

private Map<String,VehicleDetailsCollection> vehicleDetailsDTOList;

    ********************
    ********************
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

Even your `VehicleDetailsCollection` class should implement the [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface.

Implementing `Serializable` in `VehicleDetailsCollectionWrapper` class makes only the wrapper serializable and not the `VehicleDetailsCollection` class.

Comment: if my VehicleDetailsCollection object again contains object then it should also implement Serializable.

Comment: @bikash_binay - Yes exactly. All the objects you want to Serialize should implement it. `String` already implements and that's why you needn't worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make `VehicleDetailsCollection` class also Serializable.

Read Java serialization specs for more:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html